# How to extract a column from filtered dataframe in a function?

Tags: r

I am trying to wrap a function that can extract values from a data frame based on given parameters:

```r
> f <- function(df, factor, level1, level2, response) {
+     df1 <- df[df$factor == level1, ]$response
+     df2 <- df[df$factor == level2, ]$response
+     print(df1)
+     print(df2)
+ }
> f(ToothGrowth, supp, "VC", "OJ", len)
NULL
NULL
```

In the above example, the data frame is `ToothGrowth`, and the function `f` is trying to print two separated data frames: `df1` contains an array of values from rows that `supp` column is equal to `"VC"`; and "OJ" for `df2`.

The equivalent python code that uses pandas is as follows (very straightforward and works well):

```py
def f(df: pd.DataFrame, factor: str, level1: str, level2: str, response: str):
    p1 = df[df[factor] == level1][response]
    p2 = df[df[factor] == level2][response]
    print(p1, p2)
```

Why are these outputs just `NULL` in R? What would be the best practice here to achieve the goal?

I am new to R but aware of the `tidyverse`. However, it seems very strange to me, and don't really know if it is worthy to achieve this purpose to use such a heavy library.

Comment: `$` doesnt evaluate in the expression, it is more for interactive use (or if you have a column called "factor"), so you should use square brackets `df[df[, factor] == level1, ][, response]`, you would also need to add quotes `f(ToothGrowth, "supp", "VC", "OJ", "len")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite sure that you need something like this:

```
f <- function(df, factor, level, response) {
  df <- df %>% 
    dplyr::filter({{factor}}==level) %>% 
    pull({{response}})
  print(df)
  }


f(ToothGrowth, supp, "VC", len)

#gives:
 [1]  4.2 11.5  7.3  5.8  6.4 10.0 11.2 11.2  5.2  7.0 16.5 16.5 15.2 17.3 22.5
[16] 17.3 13.6 14.5 18.8 15.5 23.6 18.5 33.9 25.5 26.4 32.5 26.7 21.5 23.3 29.5
```

**Explanation**

What you produce with your function and the function call

`f(ToothGrowth, "supp", "VC", "OJ", "len")` is:

```
[1]  4.2 11.5  7.3  5.8  6.4 10.0 11.2 11.2  5.2  7.0 16.5 16.5 15.2 17.3 22.5
[16] 17.3 13.6 14.5 18.8 15.5 23.6 18.5 33.9 25.5 26.4 32.5 26.7 21.5 23.3 29.5
 [1] 15.2 21.5 17.6  9.7 14.5 10.0  8.2  9.4 16.5  9.7 19.7 23.3 23.6 26.4 20.0
[16] 25.2 25.8 21.2 14.5 27.3 25.5 26.4 22.4 24.5 24.8 30.9 26.4 27.3 29.4 23.0
```

If this is your aim (what I don't think) then you could do:

`ToothGrowth$len` gives:

```
 [1]  4.2 11.5  7.3  5.8  6.4 10.0 11.2 11.2  5.2  7.0 16.5 16.5 15.2 17.3 22.5
[16] 17.3 13.6 14.5 18.8 15.5 23.6 18.5 33.9 25.5 26.4 32.5 26.7 21.5 23.3 29.5
[31] 15.2 21.5 17.6  9.7 14.5 10.0  8.2  9.4 16.5  9.7 19.7 23.3 23.6 26.4 20.0
[46] 25.2 25.8 21.2 14.5 27.3 25.5 26.4 22.4 24.5 24.8 30.9 26.4 27.3 29.4 23.0
```

What makes more sense to me is that you need maybe something like this:

```
f <- function(df, factor, level) {
  df <- df %>% 
    dplyr::filter({{factor}}==level)
  print(df)
  }

f(ToothGrowth, supp, "VC")
```

What this function does is:

1. from any dataframe you want identify a factor column in our case `supp` (due to tidy evaluation no "".
2. filter the dataframe by the factor column identifying the factor level. I understand you may want to identify two levels. But this is easyl done by extending the filter line. In the function here we need "".

We get:

```
  len supp dose
1   4.2   VC  0.5
2  11.5   VC  0.5
3   7.3   VC  0.5
4   5.8   VC  0.5
5   6.4   VC  0.5
6  10.0   VC  0.5
7  11.2   VC  0.5
8  11.2   VC  0.5
9   5.2   VC  0.5
10  7.0   VC  0.5
11 16.5   VC  1.0
12 16.5   VC  1.0
13 15.2   VC  1.0
14 17.3   VC  1.0
15 22.5   VC  1.0
16 17.3   VC  1.0
17 13.6   VC  1.0
18 14.5   VC  1.0
19 18.8   VC  1.0
20 15.5   VC  1.0
21 23.6   VC  2.0
22 18.5   VC  2.0
23 33.9   VC  2.0
24 25.5   VC  2.0
25 26.4   VC  2.0
26 32.5   VC  2.0
27 26.7   VC  2.0
28 21.5   VC  2.0
29 23.3   VC  2.0
30 29.5   VC  2.0
```

**And this is extendable as shown at the beginning of my answer:**
For example if we want to get the vector:

just add `pull(response)` to your function after adding response to the arguments, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wonder what exactly does `{{ }}` do. Is it accessing the value of an argument from function parameter? Specifically, it remains a bit strange as a follow up use of `factor` will be treat as a formula, such as: `leveneTest(response ~ factor ...` However, it seems that the code could not find anything about `factor` or `response`. What went wrong here?

Comment: 1. {{}} is part of tidy evaluation in the family of non standard evaluation. For me it was easier to learn functions etc.. (and I am still learning) after reading Wickham Hadleys <https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/>. 2. If you intend to use a function for formulas then read about reformulate -> reformulate creates a formula from a character vector. 3. My guess is that using `$` is not appropriate in your function. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

R and Python have similarities and disimilarities. Your function in R should be writen like this:

```
f <- function(df, factor, level1, level2, response) {
  df1 <- df[df[,factor] == level1, ][,response]
  df2 <- df[df[,factor] == level2, ][,response]
  print(df1)
  print(df2)
}
```

When you write `df$factor`, you are saying that there is a column named "factor" instead of passing the value of (the object) `factor` as a name of a column.

And, as @rawr said, you have to quote the calling:

```
f(ToothGrowth, "supp", "VC", "OJ", "len")
```

This is because your are indicating the name of the columns (variables), so you are indicating names (strings), so they must be set between quotes.